# How can git grep respect UTF-8 on macOS?

Tags: git, macos, utf-8

Under macOS (Monterey) `git grep` doesn't seem to respect the UTF-8 encoding, even with `LC_ALL` and `LANG` set to `en_US.UTF-8`.  The *wc* and *grep* commands handle UTF-8 just fine.  The same `git grep` command also works fine on Linux, FreeBSD, and Cygwin.

```bash
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
$ echo ¿ >file
$ file file
file: Unicode text, UTF-8 text

$ git add file
$ git grep '^.$' file # Fails to identify the single character line
$ git grep .. file # Wrongly identifies two characters
file:¿

$ wc -m file # Correctly counts the single UTF-8 character and the newline
       2 file
$ grep .. file # Correctly doesn't find two characters
$ grep '^.$' file # Correctly identifies the single character line
¿

$ which git ; git --version
/usr/bin/git
git version 2.32.1 (Apple Git-133)
```

Comment: This is a nice reproducer; consider sending it to the Git mailing list (if you haven't already—I seem to recall something flying by about this recently).

Comment: It looks like it could be an issue of Apple's Git port, no? I'd need to compile Git from source, to allow Git's maintainers to reproduce it.

Comment: It could be. Whether it *is*, I don't know—I know Apple do something to their Git port, but I've never understood what or why.

Comment: The problem is an old limitation of the current Git configuration on macOS. I'm working on a PR to fix it. https://github.com/git/git/pull/1313